# why es6 Set prototype has values method?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

[Set.prototype.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/values) describe that values exist for similarity with [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object. I understand what it say but I don't understand why this similarity is desired?

Comment: All containers share a bunch of methods, including `Array`. Would you prefer `Set` to stand apart? Isn't it rather convenient being able to pass an arbitrary container to a function?

Answer (score 1):

Since values of a `Set` are unique, they could be thought of as keys.

> why this similarity is desired?

No idea why it would be desired. In my opinion, it would be better not to have this choice.

Comment: What's wrong with the method? Why not drop the `keys` method instead - after all, sets do contain values not keys for anything?

Comment: That is what I meant - `keys` are introduced for similarity with `Map`s, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the quote from the docs:

> The keys() method is an alias for this method (for similarity with Map objects); it behaves exactly the same and returns values of Set elements.

And it means that there's another method, `Set.prototype.keys()` which is an alias for this method (`Set.prototype.values()`) so that Set objects would be more similar to Map objects, which have both of these methods on their prototypes.